# Laravel exception "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException", despite adding except on routes

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel as a rest api. As far as I understand, when you get an error like this

```
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
```

it usually means you have some CSRF token that has not been supplied. I read about it [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/symfonycomponenthttpkernelexceptionhttpexception-exception)

Since my api does not use cookies, I don't need CSRF, which I [read here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints/218619#218619)

I generate a JWT token for access to the api, (this all works locally btw)

And in my Middleware, in the file **VerifyCsrfToken.php** I should add this line, which I have done.

```
protected $except = [
    'api/*', //No cookies = No CSRF needed
];
```

However I still get this error. Am I missing something else?
Best regards

Comment: this error also occurred when you mismatch your route

Comment: `HttpException` is a generic exception thrown for any http exception ( basically 404, 400, 500 etc ). It is not for just csrf. So your error could be anything. If its not in the logs, try logging it manually and it would show exactly where the exception occured at

Comment: Thank you, I investigated further and it was because the pem files were not loading in. Talk about a needle in a haystack.